# call sqlserver function in netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, function, call

i need help for calling sqlserver function in netbeans..
first, sorry my english so bad and a newbie..

i used this code in netbeans :

```
public void generateNoOrder()
{
    ResultSet rset = null;
    con = conf.makeConnection();
    //String result="";
    try{
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call get_date()}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
        rset = cs.executeQuery();
        //while(rset.next())
        //{
         String result = cs.getString(1);
        //}
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        //return null;
    }
    finally {
        conf.closeConnection(con, s, rset);
    }
}
```

this function doesn't need a input parameters, and this function return type char[12]

the error message is : 
Invalid parameter index 1.

please help me, thanks before !

Answer (score 0):

If no input paremeters needed and it's a function what you're calling, try without ()

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call get_date}")
```

as seen on http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/ConnectionprepareCallStringsql.htm

And because you're trying to retrieve an output parameter, you should need to register the output parameter as well, something like this

```
// Call a function with no parameters; the function returns a VARCHAR
// Prepare the callable statement
cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call get_date}");

// Register the type of the return value
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.CHAR);

// Execute and retrieve the returned value
cs.execute();
String result = cs.getString(1);
```

It worked for me when calling a MySQL function, it should work with SQL Server IMAO.

Comment: So... did it work with the code above or did you use another solution?